# jQuery autocomplete on class, how to get id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been working on this a while and can't seem to get anywhere.  Basically I have the autocomplete on a bunch of inputs by class, but I need to get the specific inputs id to build the object to post the ajax (I have to use POST for this project not GET).

```
$(".input_autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
  // here is where I get the hash from local storage,
  // reference the id and build the object
  // tried this.id, $(this).prop('id'), no luck
  $.ajax({
    url: '/somepath/filename.htm',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    success: function(json) {
      return {
        label: item.label,
        value: item.label
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      // error handling
    }
   }); // ajax
 } // source
});
```

Comment: I'm quite new to jQuery but, have you tried using attr('id') instead of .prop('id')? As far as I know, id's are attr, not props... Also, since you're using dot syntax, $(this) should be the way to go since you're targeting the jQuery object. Hope it solves the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this.element).prop("id");
```

or:

```
this.element[0].id;
```

Inside of the `source` callback, `this` refers to the widget instance. In order to get the element the widget is attached to, you should use `this.element`, which is a jQuery object.

Comment: Andrew, does it have anything to do with the .get(0) that some people use? If yes, this is something that I can't really understand. Why is it necessary to point to the element like that? =\

Comment: @7th: Please see my update. `this` inside of the autocomplete is the widget instance, so `this.element` is the element it was applied to. `element.get(0)` will get the first element of a jQuery object and is equivalent to `element[0]` above.

Comment: Well, it makes a lot of sense in this scenario, but sometimes I see people using .get(0) that I would never imagine it should be used. Unfortunately I can't think of a good example now. I'll try to pay better attention when I see that again and see if I can understand why it's been used. Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me. It was kind of your part.

Comment: Yeah, really you should just need `this.element.prop('id')`. I think the call to jQuery is redundant here.

Comment: this one; this.element[0].id;  worked for me

Comment: $(this).prop("id"); worked for me, the others kept providing "undefined"

Answer (score 4):

I tried it out in a project of mine. This worked for me:

```
$(this.element.get(0)).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

I was in a situation similar to you, `user1572796` and this is what worked for me:

```
$(this).prop("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a while piecing together a solution for this myself. In case it helps, this works for me:

call this after your class exists ( for most this is on document ready, for myself I had to call this function after a datatable initialized MyClassName)

```
  $('.MyClassName').each(function(index) {


  MyID = $(this).attr("id")

  $('#'+MyID).autocomplete({

  source: function(request, response) {


        var elementID = this.element[0].id     //!!! This is what did the trick ***


            $.ajax({
                url: "/MyController/MyFunction",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {

                    MySearchTerm: $('#'+elementID).val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                ...
```